# Google Script simple onEdit() Function not firing, works on another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm hoping this is a simple solution that I just can't think of, but I have been scouring old questions and have not found a fix that works.

For some reason my `onEdit()` function is not firing on one of my spreadsheets, yet when I use the exact same code on a new sheet it works.

When I try to view my logs on the original sheet, nothing triggered when I make edits to the sheet. I don't have a function inputting values or anything, it's just me typing.

Any ideas why my sheet isn't firing this update?

This is the only code I'm trying to run:

```
function onEdit() {
  Logger.log("Fired");
}
```

Comment: Is this a Simple Trigger or Installable?

Comment: I'm new to google script, but to my knowledge (from what ive googled) it's just a simple trigger

Comment: See view>Executions

Comment: Have you executed any functions from the "old" sheet's editor?

Comment: Welcome. Tested code, works OK as a simple trigger. So likely interference with other code in the project file (tehhowch). Open script editor, make an edit, then check the log (View>Logs). If its empty, check the Transcript (View>Execution transcript)(TheMaster). Use the script editor to find any other [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) in the project file and check their activity. Check Installable Triggers (Edit>Current project's triggers) for conflicts. When all else fails, consider deleting project, recreating and re-authorising.

Comment: @TheMaster I viewed the executions like you said and see the failed executions now. It states that: 
"ReferenceError: "e" is not defined. at [unknown function](Archive:4)"

How do I define e to get passed this?

Comment: Provide [mcve]. There is no `e` in the code above. `e` will not be defined, when you run the function manually from the script editor. Otherwise, it'll be passed automatically.

Comment: Thats exactly my issue... There is no e in my code yet it says it's failing due to an undefined e.. Thats why I'm lost. My code is exactly as written above, with no other code anywhere in the file

Comment: @Brendan Are there other files then?

Comment: @TheMaster Not that I'm aware of, there's only the one file and it's the code.gs and in that file it's only the code above. So i'm super confused where it sees me trying to declare e. Is there a way to completely delete all script files/memory.. Maybe theres something hidden thats still trying to declare that variable?

Comment: @TheMaster So i finally fixed it by restoring a version from three weeks ago and putting the code above. Apparently something hidden was happening. I appreciate the support